# Uploading and Streaming Video using Socket in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, video

I am developing an app for uploading and streaming high quality videos. Its working good so far.

But i want to improve streaming and uploading performance. I was wondering how could if i achieve this using Socket programming in iOS.

Please help. I am really running very tight. Your help both as text and/or code will be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading and streaming are generally two different things - i.e. you upload a video to a server and then you stream the video from a streaming server.

Uploading videos is well documented, either standalone or as part of the workflow for a streaming server.

The streaming server itself is quite a complicated and specialised server if you want to ensure high quality, as it appears you do. The server will generally have to handle the different formats and bit rates required for adaptive bit rate (ABR0 video streaming. Writing the server yourself would be hard and there are open source examples or commercial examples readily available:

Open source streaming servers:

- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html
- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

An example commercial streaming servers:

- https://www.wowza.com

There is an end to end iPhone to Wowza to playback on a JWPlayer client example walkthrough here which may be useful for you to look:

- https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/how-to-stream-live-video-from-your-iphone-to-the-jw-player/

Comment: Thanks buddy. It really helped me.